# Search function listing items

Tags: php, list, search

I have this little code which lists all matches of items that contains the key that haz been searched for.

The code I currently have lists all thing no matter how many times it occurs in the array.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($return); $i++) {
    $herb = explode('<+>',$return[$i]);
    $inf = explode('<+>', $njdbData[$herb[0]]);
    echo '<div class="herbListItem" onclick="goToHerb(' . $herb[0] . ')">
          <img src="../img/herbs/' . $inf[2] . '-2.jpg" />    
          <span>'.$inf[0].'<i>'.$herb[1].'</i></span></div>';
}
```

I've made so that all item ids and why the item ids are listen are in an array.
For example, if I search for "Red dragon.".

- The item with id 1 got listed because I searched for "dragon".
- The item with id 3 got listed because I searched for "dragon".
- The item with id 4 got listed because I searched for "China".
- The item with id 1 got listed again because I searched for "red".

Because there was 2 hits for item 1 I want item 1 to show up only once and on the top...

In the code herb[0] returns the id of the item and herb[1] returns why the item is in the array.

Can anyone help me making it so it echos out a list where, in the example, instead of echoing this out when searching for "Red dragon":

- Item 1, Because you searched for Dragon
- Item 3, Because you searched for Dragon
- Item 4, Because you searched for China
- Item 1, Because you searched for red

it echoes out this:

- Item 1, Because you searched for Dragon and red
- Item 3, Because you searched for Dragon
- Item 4, Because you searched for China

I hope you understand what I'm trying to achieve here.

Thanks in advance, enji

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another array that keeps track of which ones have been echoed out.

```
$used_ones= array();
$pre_sort = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($return); $i++) {
    $name =  explode('<+>',$return[$i]);
    array_push($pre_sort, $name[0]);
}
$sorted = array_count_values($pre_sort);
arsort($sorted, SORT_NUMERIC);
foreach($sorted as $key=>$val) {
   for ($i = 0; $i < count($return); $i++) {
        $herb = explode('<+>',$return[$i]);
        if($herb[0] == $key){
            $inf = explode('<+>', $njdbData[$herb[0]]); 
            echo '<div class="herbListItem" onclick="goToHerb(' . $herb[0] . ')"><img src="../img/herbs/' . $inf[2] . '-2.jpg" /> <span>'.$inf[0].'<i>'.$herb[1].'</i></span></div>';
            break;
        }

   }
}
```

Adding multiple reasons why a line was printed doesn't seem possible with how you are doing this because the $inf variale gets overwrriten each time through the for loop. With some tinkering in your process you'll be able to print out multiple reasons why a value was returned. But this should eliminate your muultiple responses.

EDIT: Give this a shot. I'm not sure how the array_count_values will act because I don't know what you have in $return[n]. **Code has not been tested.**

EDIT#2: I'm an idiot and forgot to sort the array from High to Low based on value. That's been added.

Comment: Ok, it only displays once now, but I need to make sure that the one with most matches will diplay on top :/

Comment: I don't want the reason to be printed out, I only took that into the array to be able possibly count how many times and why they matched the keywords

Comment: Thanks for your help so far anyways! :D

Comment: No problem. This can be accomplished but you're going to have to switch up your method completely, because you have to count the number of times a variable is added before you print anything. it can be done, hold on I'll work on a solution.

Comment: Ok this is me full code for the search thing:
http://www.pastie.org/3091744

If you wonder; 'dRvHj8' is the value set if ?q= isn't in the url ( $search = isset($_GET['q']) ? $_GET['q'] : 'dRvHj8'; )

Comment: Can you print out a possible value for $return[0]?

Comment: That gave me this: http://flora.enji.se/vaxter/?q=%C3%A4ng+gr%C3%B6n+dagg

It listed them 3 times in a row, but showed 3 :P

Comment: It broke here I guess... http://flora.enji.se/vaxter/?q=%C3%A4ng+druid+gr%C3%B6n -- Current code now; http://www.pastie.org/3091936

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6247/discussion-between-matt-moore-and-enjikaka)